# PHP How to show all results from db if the user selects "ALL" option from select list options

Tags: php, mysql, select, search, selectlist

Hi :) I have a form that contains select lists and search button to show result from the database in a table. The first option of all my select lists are "ALL" (This is not from the database! Basically it supposes to bring all data from the database when user clicks Search without selecting any specific option). The current code works fine if I select real options (not the first option "ALL"). My question is: How to bring all the data if the user selects "ALL" in one select list, or in all select lists?

```
<!-- Search Components -->
<div class="row">
  <form action="search.php" method="POST" name="" class="text-center">

    <!-- Username -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <?php
        include("dbc.php");
        $qq = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users ORDER BY username";
        $rr = mysqli_query($dbc,$qq);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rr)){
          $username_array[] = $row['username'];
        }
        echo '<select class="form-control border-input" name="username">';
        echo '<option value="all">ALL</option>';
        foreach($username_array as $user){
          $selected = '';
          if($_POST['username'] == $user) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
          }
          echo '<option value="'.$user.'"'.$selected.'>'.$user.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
      ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Hospital Sections -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <?php
        include("dbc.php");
        $qqq = "SELECT DISTINCT section_name FROM hospital_sections ORDER BY section_name";
        $rrr = mysqli_query($dbc,$qqq);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rrr)){
          $sections_array[] = $row['section_name'];
        }
        echo '<select class="form-control border-input" name="section_name">';
        echo '<option value="all">ALL</option>';
        foreach($sections_array as $sec){
          $selected = '';
          if($_POST['section_name'] == $sec) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
          }
          echo '<option value="'.$sec.'"'.$selected.'>'.$sec.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
      ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Room Number -->

    <!-- Qeblah Status -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control border-input" name="qeblah_status">
        <option <?php if($_POST['qeblah_status'] == "ALL") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="all">ALL</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['qeblah_status'] == "yes") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['qeblah_status'] == "no") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Prayer Painting -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control border-input" name="prayer_painting">
        <option <?php if($_POST['prayer_painting'] == "ALL") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="all">ALL</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['prayer_painting'] == "yes") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['prayer_painting'] == "no") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Fatwah -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control border-input" name="fatwa_status">
        <option <?php if($_POST['fatwa_status'] == "ALL") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="all">ALL</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['fatwa_status'] == "yes") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option <?php if($_POST['fatwa_status'] == "no") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="no">No</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Search Button -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success btn-fill btn-wd" name="submit" value="Search"><i class="ti-search"></i> Search </button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div> <!-- .row Ends -->
<!-- Search Components Ends -->

<hr>

<!-- Search Results -->

<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $section_name = $_POST['section_name'];
    $qeblah_status = $_POST['qeblah_status'];
    $prayer_painting = $_POST['prayer_painting'];
    $fatwa_status = $_POST['fatwa_status'];
    ?>

    <!-- The Table -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="border-style: hidden;">
              <thead>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Section Name</th>
                <th>Room Number</th>
                <th>Qeblah</th>
                <th>Prayer Painting</th>
                <th>Fatwah</th>
                <th>Condition</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
                        $selected_username = "";
                        if($username != 'All'){
                            $selected_username = "username = '$username'";
                        }
                        $selected_section_name = "";
                        if($section_name != 'All'){
                            $selected_section_name = "section_name = '$section_name'";
                        }
                        $selected_qeblah_status = "";
                        if($qeblah_status != 'All'){
                            $selected_qeblah_status = "qeblah_status = '$qeblah_status'";
                        }
                        $selected_prayer_painting = "";
                        if($prayer_painting != 'All'){
                            $selected_prayer_painting = "prayer_painting = '$prayer_painting'";
                        }
                        $selected_fatwa_status = "";
                        if($fatwa_status != 'All'){
                            $selected_fatwa_status = "fatwa_status = '$fatwa_status'";
                        }
                include("dbc.php");
                $q = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE $selected_username AND $selected_section_name AND $selected_qeblah_status AND $selected_prayer_painting AND $selected_fatwa_status";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['section_name']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['room_number']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['qeblah_status']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['prayer_painting']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['fatwa_status']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['report_status']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                  }
              ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
          </div> <!-- .content Ends -->
        </div> <!-- .card Ends -->
      </div> <!-- .col-md-12 Ends -->
    </div> <!-- .row Ends -->
  }

<!-- Search Results Ends -->

</div> <!-- .container-fluid Ends -->
</div> <!-- .content Ends -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of suggesting solutions, I had a go at the code myself.  I modified the page a bit to make it work without a database.  The important part is the bottom section.

I took out the table formatting, what I concentrated on is to build the query dynamicly based on the users's choice.  To understand:

- when a user selects ALL, there is nothing to filter on, so it is not even mentioned in the $query.
- If a user selects ALL for all the fields, there is no need for a WHERE clause in the query ($query remains empty).
- In a user selects more than one field to be other than ALL, each WHERE item must be separated by "AND".  So we must add "AND" in the $query.

So the code I produced and tested is this (the bottom section, I did not change the rest):

```
<div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
          <?php
                    $where = "";
                    $query = "";

                    if($username != 'all'){
                        $query = "username = '$username'";
                        $where = "WHERE ";
                    }

                    if($section_name != 'all'){
                        if (strlen($query) != 0)
                        {
                            $query = $query . " AND ";
                        }
                        $query = $query . "section_name = '$section_name'";
                        $where = "WHERE ";
                    }

                    if($qeblah_status != 'all'){
                        if (strlen($query) != 0)
                        {
                            $query = $query . " AND ";
                        }
                        $query = $query . "qeblah_status = '$qeblah_status'";
                        $where = "WHERE ";
                    }

                    if($prayer_painting != 'all'){
                        if (strlen($query) != 0)
                        {
                            $query = $query . " AND ";
                        }
                        $query = $query . "prayer_painting = '$prayer_painting'";
                        $where = "WHERE ";
                    }

                    if($fatwa_status != 'all'){
                        if (strlen($query) != 0)
                        {
                            $query = $query . " AND ";
                        }
                        $query = $query . "fatwa_status = '$fatwa_status'";
                        $where = "WHERE ";
                    }

            $q = "SELECT * FROM reports $where $query";
            echo "<h1>$q</h1>\n";
          ?>
      </div>
```

So your query changes dynamically.  You can then run it and display the output.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you want to modify your $q query for items that are selected as "ALL".

The query limits the number of returned values in the WHERE part of it.  So if a user selects ALL, just remove that part of query.

I will do for the username part, you can use the same concept for the rest:

```
$username_part = "";
if ($username != 'ALL')
{
    $username_part = "username = '$username' AND";
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE $username_part section_name = '$section_name' AND qeblah_status = '$qeblah_status' AND prayer_painting = '$prayer_painting' AND fatwa_status = '$fatwa_status'";
```

This way, if a user selects ALL, you do not specify a WHERE condition on it.  You just take it all.  If a user selects one value, it adds a condition in the WHERE, based on the user's selection.

Managing the results of such queries is left to you :-)
Obviously, if the username is named "ALL", you have a problem :-)

Comment: Logically your answer is right. However, I don't know why it doesn't work with me until now. I'll try it again.

Comment: I noticed that the " " doesn't bring all data from the database! Any other ideas for the value of $username_part that will executed in the query?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Ya... I look at my code, it's not going to work without some tweeking...  Done.  My previous version was doing WHERE AND section_name = ...  Not good.  But the idea is if the user selects ALL, do not include that section in your WHERE portion of the SQL statement.

Comment: Yeah I've already updated the query to have the same concept like $username_part, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I will update the code on my question so you can see what I've done until now.

Comment: Please see the updated code on the question to figure out what I'm missing. Thank you so much for your time my friend :)